# How to INDEX MATCH return multiple words between sheets

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

In sheet 1 column 1 is a vertical list of words (e.g. A1:A25).

In sheet 1 column 2 I want to randomly put multiple X’s (e.g. in a few cells between B1:B25).

In sheet 2 I want to return whatever words are to the left of the X’s in sheet 1. How would I do this?

Im currently returning one word using the following formula:

=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A25,MATCH("X",Sheet!B1:B25,0))

What formula would return multiple words to sheet2 from column 1 of sheet1 (via X’s in the second column of sheet1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dynamic array formula available in Office 365, use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B="X")
```

Put that in the first cell and the results will automatically spill down.

With older versions, put this in the first cell and copy/drag down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25)/(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25="X"),Row($ZZ1))),"")
```